# C# asp.net external authentication and HostAuthentication filter for mvc (not webapi) controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

i have spent a lot of time trying to find Host Authentication filter for mvc controller, but i found nothing.

I want to implement external login with Google. It was fine if i use webapi controller, but now i would like to do the same with mvc controller.
The problem (i suppose) is in HostAuthentication.

```
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [System.Web.Http.HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("externallogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
```

Is there any HostAuthentication dedicated for mvc controller?